# OS platform porting are included in term 'Derivatives' in Creative Commons?

Tags: legal, software, creative-commons

Taken this license for reference:
[Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International (CC BY-NC-ND 4.0)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/)

([similar question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/what-can-open-data-with-a-cc-by-nc-nd-creative-commons-attribution-noncommerc))

Quote:

> **Share** — copy and redistribute the material **in any medium or format**
>
> **NoDerivatives** — If you remix, **transform, or build** upon the material, you may not distribute the modified material.
>
> You do not have to comply with the license for elements of the
>   material in the public domain or where your use is permitted by an
>   applicable exception or limitation.

It seems like self-contradictory and confusing. Should below situation mean that it’s a 'Derivative'?

1. Keep the original content (data), no addition, no deletion.
2. Port into different OS platform.
3. Different GUI (platform based) but mode of operations remain the same.
4. Proper credited to original author.

Please exclude the situation of 'contacting author, he might be happy if you do work for him'.